# Making a matrix transitive R

Tags: r, matrix

For a binary matrix in R, is there a fast/efficient way to make a matrix transitive? That is, if [i, j] == 1, and [i, k] == 1, set [j, k] = 1. For example, say we have a square matrix of individuals, and a 1 in a row/column means that they are related. Is there fast way to figure out which individuals are in some way related?

Take the matrix Mx

```
 Mx a b c d e
 a  1 1 0 1 0
 b  0 1 0 0 0 
 c  0 0 1 1 0
 d  0 0 0 1 0
 e  0 0 0 0 1
```

Since [a, b] == 1, and [a,d] == 1, [b,d] and [d, b] should be set to 1.
 Similarly, [c, d] == 1, and since a, b, and d are related, there should be 1s for a,b,c,d. The final matrix would look like this, and should be symmetric across the diagonal.

```
Mx a b c d e 
 a 1 1 1 1 0
 b 1 1 1 1 0
 c 1 1 1 1 0
 d 1 1 1 1 0 
 e 0 0 0 0 1
```

So for the family example, this would mean a, b, c, and d are related in some way.
Right now I have a function that computes this second matrix, but it runs in n^3 time, where n is the number of rows/columns. Is there a faster way to do this?Thanks

n^3 function:

```
   # Repeat loop three times for completion
     for (rep in 1:3) {
   # For every individual i
       for (i in 1:N) {
   # For every individual j
         for (j in 1:N) {
   # For every individual k
           for (k in 1:N) {
    # If i and j are related and j and k are related
            if (Mx[i,j] == 1 && Mx[j, k] == 1) {
        #i and k are related
              Mx[i,k] <- 1
              Mx[k,i] <- 1
                    }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Why you don't show use your `n^3` function?

Comment: I added the function to the question

Comment: `library(sos); ???"transitive closure"`
suggests `relations::transitive_closure`
(with an O(n^3) algorithm). Do you want the transitive closure (as in your title) or an equivalence relation (a symmetric matrix, as in your example)?

Comment: Is the result you show really what you want to obtain from the input data? I don't see how it matches the description you give. Perhaps updating the explanation a bit will help.

Comment: @Vincent I want to take a given binary matrix and output a binary matrix that has transitive closure.

Comment: @Simon  I tried to update the explanation to give a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: 3 iterations are not enough: take the relation `k≼k+1`, where `k` varies from `0` to some large number...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding the equivalence relation associated to an arbitrary relation
boils down to finding the connected components of the corresponding graph.
It can be done with 
[depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).
It is already implemented in the `igraph` package.

```
library(igraph)
n <- 5
A <- matrix( sample(0:1, n^2, prob=c(.8,.2), replace=T), n, n)
A
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    1    0    1
# [4,]    1    0    1    0    1
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
i <- clusters(graph.adjacency(A))$membership
B <- A
B[] <- i[row(A)] == i[col(A)]
B
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    0    1    1    1
# [2,]    0    1    0    0    0
# [3,]    1    0    1    1    1
# [4,]    1    0    1    1    1
# [5,]    1    0    1    1    1
```

If you wanted the transitive and reflexive closure (reflexive, transitive, but not necessarily symmetric -- this example was already transitive, but not reflexive):

```
library(relations)
 relation_incidence( reflexive_closure( transitive_closure( as.relation(A) ) ) )
# Incidences:
#   1 2 3 4 5
# 1 1 0 0 0 0
# 2 0 1 0 0 0
# 3 0 0 1 0 1
# 4 1 0 1 1 1
# 5 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It appears to be working. 
I think I meant symmetric and not reflexive in the question.

Comment: Hey, sorry for not asking this earlier. But could you explain how this works mathematically?

Comment: The algorithm uses [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming):
build a 3-dimensional boolean array with `A[i,j,k]=1` 
if there is a path between nodes `i` and `j` using only nodes `1,2,...k`.
The `k+1`st slice can be computed from the `k`th slice:
`A[i,j,k+1] = A[i,j,k] or A[i,k,k] and A[k,j,k]`.
The result is the last slice `A[,,n]`.
This is the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) (but instead of computing shortest paths with an array containing distances, we are only interested on the existence of a path).